# Getting different result for std:sort in c++ when using similar compare function

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I am trying to sort the array using the absolute value of arr[i] - X. X is the value provided in the program. I am getting different result for the two compare that I am passing to the std::sort. Can someone explain why these two compare are producing different results.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct  {
int x;
bool operator()(int a, int b) const
    {   
        return abs(a-x) < (b-x);
    }   

}customCompare;

void rearrange2(int arr[], int n , int x) {
customCompare.x = x;
std::sort(arr, arr+n, customCompare);    

}

void rearrange1(int arr[], int n , int x) {

std::sort(arr, arr+n, [x](int a , int b) {return abs(a-x) < abs(b-x);});
}
void printArray(int arr[] , int n)
{
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{

int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
int x = 7;
int arr1[] = {10, 5, 3, 9 ,2};
cout << "\n rearrange 1\n";
rearrange1(arr1,n,x);
printArray(arr1,n);

int arr2[] = {10, 5, 3, 9 ,2};
cout << "\n rearrage 2 \n";
rearrange2(arr2,n,x);
printArray(arr2,n);
return 0;
}
```

Output I am getting is

rearrange 1
5 9 10 3 2 
 rearrage 2 
5 10 3 9 2

Comment: One uses `abs` on both sides. The other doesn't.

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`

What's arr and where did you get it from?
From what it looks like, n is bigger then 5, which is the size of arr1 and arr2.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because `abs(a-x) < (b-x)` is not equivalent to `abs(a-x) < abs(b-x)`.
I guess it's just a typo on your end.